# Move paper-tabs to the left in Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

How do I align my paper-tabs to the left? I tried using `margin-left: 0;` but that did not work. When I inspected the HTML file from the browser there seems to be a paper-icon button next to the tabs, which I did not add. It's there probably because of the scrollable attribute of the paper tab so how do I move it to the left without compromising the scrollable attribute of the paper-tabs?

[image: Web page]

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Website metadata-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <!--Polymer elements-->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Main stylesheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <!--Style for polymer elements-->
    <style is="custom-style">
        app-header{
            background: #FFFFFF;
        }
        paper-toolbar{
            --paper-toolbar-background: #ffffff;
            color: #000000;
        }
        paper-tabs{
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            width: 100%;
            text-transform: none;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            color: #757575;
            --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: #1db886;
        }
        paper-tab{
            --paper-tab-ink: #ffffff;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        paper-tab.iron-selected{
            color: #1db886;
        }
        #app-title{
            font-size: xx-large;
            font-weight: 200;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--App header-->
    <app-header reveals shadow>
        <paper-toolbar>
            <div class="title" id="app-title">Test</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <paper-tabs selected="0" scrollable>
            <paper-tab>Home</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Test</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Test</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Test</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Test</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
    </app-header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using some properties like `scrollable` in `paper-tabs` element?
some code could be helpful

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský Yes, I am using scrollable. Please see the edit for the code.

Comment: @KubaŠimonovský Edit added.

Comment: scrollable property add arrows to the left and to the right. Are you sure, you need that ? if you want just hide that margin you have 2 options. Set `hide-scroll-buttons` property, or remove `scrollable` property.

Comment: Thanks! hide-scroll-buttons worked for me. I want to users ti be able to scroll the tabs because it looks neater on mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a snippet of some of the css would help :P Try this, tho!

```
float:left;
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I have added the code. Please see the edit.